# Make asp:menu expand to left

Tags: asp.net

I have asp:menu and I want it to expand to left always.

This is the menu code

```
<asp:Menu ID="MultiLevelMenu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="100" orientation="Vertical" CssClass="MLMmenuV"> 
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="MLMmvC" />
                        <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="MLMmvoC" />
                        <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="MLMmenuVsub" />
                        <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="MLMsubmvC" />
                        <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="MLMsubmvoC" />
                    </asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do that is to put the whole list inside a div and set the "dir" property to "rtl" as following:

```
<div dir="rtl">
//menu's code here
</div>
```